# Updating an Observable Collection in C# and change color of text in list view

Tags: c#, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have an `ObservableCollection` which holds different properties values. I have a `Listview` in my XAML, that is bound to the `ObservableCollection`.

In the `ListView`, I have a Label that has a property `TextColor` which is bound to a property. As it can be seen in the code snippet below, there is a value false. This indicates the text in the Label should be red.

What I want to achieve is to change this value of false to true after a time interval, lets say 5 seconds. And the corresponding `TextColor` in the label will of color Blue.

Note that I have already implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged in my Model. Can somebody help me to simulate the above for me?

ObservableCollection detectedTruck= new ObservableCollection();

```
        for (int i = 0; i<12; i++)
        {
            detectedTruck.Add(new Truck(i, "Truck" + i, "5555", false));
        }

            listView.ItemsSource = detectedTruck;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                foreach (var tags in detectedTruck)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    tags.Transfer = true;
                }
            });
```

In my Model :

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private int _id;

public int Id
{
    get { return _id; }
    set
    {
        _id = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private string _uid;
public string UID
{
    get { return _uid; }
    set
    {
        _uid = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public bool Transfer { get; set; }

private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are speaking of Model, Bindings and ObservableCollections etc, I assume you are going with the MVVM pattern here?

```
ObservableCollection<Truck> DetectedTrucks = new ObservableCollection<Truck>();

for (int i = 0; i<12; i++)
    DetectedTrucks.Add(new Truck(1, "Truck" + i,  false));
```

Make sure your `Truck` class also implements INotifyPropertyChanged - in the setter of that bool property Transfer you should call `OnProperyChanged(nameof(Transfer))`.

```
private bool _transfer;

public bool Transfer
{
    get { return _transfer; }
    set { _transfer = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Transfer)); }
}
```

Make sure your ListBox (or ListView)'s ItemsSource is bound to your collection.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DetectedTrucks}" ...
```

Call an async method which updates your entities.

```
 private async Task ChangeTrucksAsync()
 {
     foreach (Truck t in DetectedTrucks)
     {
         t.Transfer = true; // this also calls OnProperyChanged(nameof(Transfer))
        // WPF will  reevaluate the binding, and your XAML style/value converter then changes the color to Blue

         await Task.Delay(500); // return to UI thread for 500ms, updating items one by one. 
     }
 }
```

**How are you triggering the code that changes the Truck entities?** With a button in your UI? If so I would use a RelayCommand;

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangeTrucksCommand}" ...
```

And finally in your ViewModel;

```
private RelayCommand _changeTrucksCommand;

public RelayCommand ChangeTrucksCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_changeTrucksCommand == null)
            _changeTrucksCommand = new RelayCommand(async o => await ChangeTrucksAsync());

            return _changeTrucksCommand;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `await ChangeTrucksAsync()`, also do add for doing so the main caller has to be `Async`, else you cannot Await an Async method

Comment: i was just about to ask that, I was still editing my answer.

Comment: Use case also needs `ChangeTrucksAsync` needs to be called post certain time duration and also a repeated call I assume. something like what Timer thread does

Comment: None  the less @jones, Async -Await ensures update using calling Synchronization context, UI context here, thus there are never thread safety issues

Comment: Thansk bro. Works like charm :)

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew()` should be avoided. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Comment: @FredrikRedin True, but it can be replaced by `Task.Run`

Comment: @jones glad i could help. 
yes exactly Mrinal.

Comment: Challenge though there would be Thread safe update to the `ObservableCollection`, which is not by default `ThreadSafe`

Comment: thats another issue for another day..  use a `lock`? or one of the collections in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace?

Comment: No not Concurrent collection that's not `IObservable`, they would not implement Notify property change, better option is the one depicted [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/998619/Thread-Safe-ObservableCollection-T)

Comment: I personally like this approach, Async Await is always a good solution, but @FredrikRedin. you may still need a Timer to Invoke the same after certain duration

Comment: For this approach +1, @jones, consider marking an answer, which helps you resolve the question

Comment: @FredrikRedin

My scenario is that after a detection round of trucks, my listview gets populated with the truck data. Then, as each truck is detected, from that list that gets populated with detected truck,  the corresponding data is sent to a remote DB. If the transfer is successful, the UI is updated with a blue text color. Hence, in this optic.. which method is best ?

Comment: @jones Not sure what you're asking me, but in the `ChangeTrucksAsync()` method we are waiting for 500ms for really no reason other then to "simulate" a call to a slow remote db. In your production code you should call your db remote directly for each truck, thus  `await Task.Delay(500)` should be replaced with `await SendTruckDataToRemoteAsync(t)` (and you shouldnt be waiting any extra time at all).

Answer (score 1):

After adding the new Trucks to the Observeable collection you could start a Task or Thread, pass the list of trucks and than let the task sleep for desired amount of time. Then you can change the property from false to true.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{                           

    Thread.Sleep(Delay before first change in ms);
        foreach (truck in detectedTruck )
        {
               Thread.Sleep(Delay between the items);
               truck.PropertyToChange = true;
        }                                      
});
```

Comment: Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: Add something like this:

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                  {                           
                                      
                                          Thread.Sleep(5000);
                                          foreach (truck in detectedTruck )
                                          {
                                              truck.PropertyToChange = true;
                                          }
                                      
                                  });

Comment: Changing a model on a separate thread w/o necessary protection like Lock is a sure shot recipe for race condition / data corruption

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But when I apply the code, and run the application. All the items' color have already changed. 

I want to see the color effect to change one by one. Please advise on how can I achieve this.

Comment: Items color change as underlying properties change in a separate loop, you introduce a perceptible delay like 500 ms while changing each property value, this would ensure change in color one after another

Comment: @CarsTen Thread Safety for data collection update, that's missing

Comment: Thats right - the property of class Truck should be thread safe

Comment: Thanks again. But I notice that only the first two items are changing color. The rest are remaining red. Even I decrease the delay.

Comment: You are missing OnPropertyChanged for the Transfer property!

Comment: Thansk bro. Works like charm :)

Comment: @CarsTen, please change it to `Task.Run`, that's a better option than `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: As suggested by Frederik, Async Await is a better option here